# QMovie play state notification

Tags: qt

Is there any notification I can use to determine whether a QMovie is playing or not?

Answer (score 2):

There is [QMovie::state()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmovie.html#state) and [QMovie::stateChanged()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmovie.html#stateChanged). The first one gives you [QMovie::MovieState](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmovie.html#MovieState-enum), whereas the second emits a signal that you can use in a slot (see [Signals and Slots](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/signalsandslots.html)) to detect state changes.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it exists the [QTimeLine](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtimeline.html) class which you can control the state (paused, stoped, started...) and lots of things more of the playing item (music, movie or whatever).

See you!